# FirstOrDefault python

Tags: python, linq

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в python функция LINQ как в C# FirstOrDefault?
У меня имеется список, содержащий словари:

```py
ls = [
       {'id': 23, 'name': 'John'},
       {'id': 58, 'name': 'Maria'}
     ]
```

Как мне вернуть из этого списка, словарь, где `id=58`?
В C# можно сделать следующим образом:

```cs
var value = ls.FirstOrDefault(l => l['id'] == 58)
```

Есть ли в python что-то подобное? Или мне придётся через `for` все значения перебирать?
Буду очень благодарен любой помощи

Comment: придётся через for все значения перебирать

Comment: Очень жаль(
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Например, так: `print([x for x in ls if x['id'] == 58][0])`

Comment: @gil9red, вариант "по умолчанию" упадет с ошибкой.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ага, тогда: `print(next((x for x in ls if x['id'] == 58), None))`, но тут уж лучше `filter` использовать, что и было в ответе :)

Comment: @gil9red, такой странный вариант:  `print(([x for x in ls if x['id'] == 58] + [None])[0])`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy В варианте со списковым сокращением теряется вся прелесть от частичности перебора в случае нахождения нужного элемента до окончания перебираемого списка. Без `next` частичность никак не обеспечить, так то я изначально тоже делал что-то типа `список or None`

Comment: @CrazyElf, согласен. Вариант без `next` и ленивый: `tuple(itertools.islice(itertools.chain(filter(pred, seq), (default, )), 1))[0]`. Очень громоздкий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Совсем аналогичная конструкция будет выглядеть несколько более тяжеловесно:

```py
ls = [{'id': 23, 
    'name': 'John'},
    {'id': 58,
    'name': 'Maria'}]

print(next(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == 58, ls), None))
```

Аналогии тут примерно такие:

| Python | C# |
| --- | --- |
| `filter(lambda x: x['id'] == 58, ...)` | `(l => l['id'] == 58)` |
| `next(..., None)` | `FirstOrDefault(...)` |